# Docusign API integration

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign REST API to embed signature in the document. I am able to login, create envelope, create recipient view, it takes me to the DocuSign page to capture signature. When I click on the signature icon it takes me to authentication page(single sign on) after authenticating it returns back and then I am getting the an error Popup. In the popup its just showing "ERROR" and OK button.

**ISSUE: I am performing an integration between Archer and Client Single Sign On(Okta) Docusign environment. We have developed API code for this integration and have been testing it. When testing it with the Client Single Sign On(Okta) we receive the error below when trying to sign the document. When we test it with the Docusign demo environment (non Client Single Sign On(Okta)) the code works fine and we experience expected functionality. The error message below isn’t provide us enough information to understand what the issue is and we’d like some support to further understand the root cause of the issue**

[image]

Comment: Can you add a better description such as code ? screenshots ? Typically, the authentication happens before even accessing the documents

Comment: Please supply the envelope create and recipient view request payloads from your API calls. Use the API logger: https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging Remove private info including email addresses and integration keys. EDIT your question to include the additional information. (Don't add the information as an answer.)

Comment: I checked in logs and found no error on the log file

Comment: @ArunKumarPonnuswamy: Did you enable logs just before starting the flow (logs limit is 50) and went back to that link to download the log zip after completing flow when you get this error? And can you share how you test it (with steps please) differently between Okta and DocuSign Demo?